# How to determine from which index a button was clicked in an accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion, multipartform-data

I am using jQuery Accordion UI with a multipart form (w/ validation and form plugins). Each form has a regular submit button and an edit button. The edit button will trigger a submission of the currently open section if that section is complete, or close that active section if it is not yet completed. The accordion will then open to the section where the edit button was clicked.

For example, user fills in section 1, then clicks continue. While filling in section 2, the user realizes that he or she made a mistake and clicks on the edit button within section 1. Section 2 is closed, and section 1 is reopened for editing. I would like to know which index contained the edit button that triggered section 2 to close (in this instance it was the index associated with the first section).

I cannot figure out how to determine from which section (index) the edit button was clicked. When I use the following code within the submitHandler, I do not get the correct index.

```
var acc = $("#accordion"),
index = acc.accordion('option','active'),
index_origin = $(".edit").index(this);
alert(index_origin);
```

Any suggestions?

I apologize in advance for the clumsy code - I'm new to this.

UPDATE: Below, as requested in the comments, here is the HTML from the first section of the accordion.

```
<h3 id="section1"><a href="#" class="">Applicant Information</a><button id="edit-applicant-button" class="edit" value="edit" name="edit">Edit Applicant information</button></h3>
        <div id="applicant-information" class="step">   
                <form id="applicant-form" class="registration-form" name="applicant-form" method="post" action="">
                    <fieldset id="clientInfo">                  
. . .   
                        </div>
                        <div class="step-action">
                            <p>
                                <span class="next-step">
                                    <button id="submit-first" class="submit" type="submit" value="next" name="next"><em>Next</em></button>
                                </span>
                            </p>
                        </div><
                    </fieldset>         
                </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you post a bit of your HTML markup?

Comment: Please explain this a little bit more: "The edit button will submit the open section before it opens the other section where the edit button was clicked"

Comment: I have edited the post to clarify. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that the actual class of your button is `"edit"`, not `"editButton"`. So you'd have to change it in the html, OR change your javascript to this:

```
index_origin = $("#accordion .edit").index(this);
```

Adding the `#accordion` to the selector is not mandatory, but will allow you to have one or many accordions.

**EDIT**. With the extra information you supplied, the solution would be this:

```
$("#accordion .edit").click(function(){
    window.lastButtonClicked = this;  //Store clicked button in a global var.
});

...
submitHandler: function(){
   var index_origin = $("#accordion .edit").index(window.lastButtonClicked );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, from within submitHandler, I am still not able to get the index from where the edit button was clicked. I have edited my post to avoid any further confusion.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick. Is there any reason why the index is one less than it is supposed to be (e.g., the first index is -1, not 0)?

Comment: Also, what if I wanted to find out the value or name of the edit button as well as the index?

Comment: You already have the index. For the name, you could do: `$(window.lastButtonClicked).attr("name")`

Comment: That doesn't work. It says the name is undefined. I will post this question as a separate post since it is slightly different than my original post.

Answer (score 0):

The selected section in accodion gives the active class. You find the `h` tag that has the active class

```
$('#acordion h').hasclass('active').index()
```